# Render list of items in a component attached by router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I would like to list the items, and display the detail when an item got clicked.

The script looks like below:

```
const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
  },
];


const List = Vue.component('list', {
  template: `
    <h1> Total {{items.length}} item(s)</h1>
    <div v-for="item in items" v-bind:id="'cid_'+item.id">
      {{item.id}}
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      items,
    };
  },
});

const Detail = {
  template: 'Viewing: {{item.id}}',
};

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: List,
  },
  {
    path: '/item/:id',
    component: Detail,
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes,
});


let vm = new Vue({
  router,
}).$mount('#page');
```

When I go to '/', it returns only "Total 2 item(s)". The list of items doesn't render as expected.

[image]

What's wrong with my code? How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Try putting the whole template code in one div, as template should have only one root element.

Answer (score 1):

not super familiar with Vue.js and I don't know what your end goal is here but when I loaded this up in `index.html` with some CDN links I got an error that said all components must return only one element so I wrapped it in a `<div></div>` . and it is showing the items at root, here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nvd37s2f/).

Comment: interesting stuff, playing around with the router and params a bit:  [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/ed42311/5dd552f6cf0583f2c85fc50b8c1daaa2)